# hook_menu_alter() with node URL alias

Tags: 7, routes, hooks

I have a node with ID equal to 60, which has a URL alias that is "mynodes/about-us." I would like to change the access callback of that node to `myfunction()`.

It doesn't work when I use the URL alias:

```
function celsis_forms_menu_alter(&$items) {
    $items['mynodes/about-us']['access callback'] = myfunction;
}

function myfunction() {
     return FALSE;
}
```

But it works when I use the node number:

```
$items['node/60']['access callback'] = myfunction;
```

How can I get the url alias to work and would it be possible to change the `access callback` for all nodes with alias starting with `mynodes/*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that because when Drupal invokes `hook_menu()` and `hook_menu_alter()` the value contained in `$_GET['q']`, which is used to find the menu callback to use, has been already changed from the path alias to the normal path.
[drupal_path_initialize()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/drupal_path_initialize/7), which is called by `drupal_bootstrap()` contains the following code:

```
  if (!empty($_GET['q'])) {
    $_GET['q'] = drupal_get_normal_path($_GET['q']);
  }
  else {
    $_GET['q'] = drupal_get_normal_path(variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node'));
  }
```

What you are trying to achieve can be accomplished in another way: implementing [hook_node_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7). Differently from the equivalent hook in Drupal 6, it can be implemented also from modules that don't define a new content type.

```
function mymodule_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  if ($op == 'view') {
    $path_alias = request_path();
    // ...
  }
}
```

`$account` contains the user object to which is being given access to the node. If the hook returns `NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW`, then the user has access to the node for the operation passed in `$op`; if the hook returns `NODE_ACCESS_DENY`, the user doesn't have access to the node; when it returns `NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE`, it leaves to other modules the decision.

[request_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/request_path/7) returns the path alias if one was used. This means that if the user is using a URL like example.com/node/60, it returns "node/60"; if the user is using 
example.com/mynodes/about-us, which is an alias for example.com/node/60, it returns "mynodes/about-us." In the case the user is using example.com/index.php, the function returns an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

How about this? It's a bit of a simpler alternative. I'm guessing that you want the access callback to continue functioning even if you later create a new node and give it this same alias:

```
    function celsis_forms_menu_alter(&$items) {
      // Retrieve the Drupal system path for the page's alias
      $about_us_path = drupal_get_normal_path('mynodes/about-us');
      $items[$about_us_path]['access callback'] = 'myfunction';
    }

    function myfunction() {
      return FALSE;
    }
```

Note that if you do point this alias at a different node, you will need to clear the cache for this logic to keep working. `hook_menu_alter` is called when the menu is rebuilt.

Comment: Drupal doesn't define a menu callback for "node/60"; using that hook implementation, you are probably going to get a partial menu callback definition.

Comment: kiamlaluno is right -- you need to `if (!isset($items[$about_us_path])) $items[$about_us_path] = $items['node/%'];` just before the `'myfunction'`.

Comment: The OP said node/60 worked, so I was running with that assumption. If it doesn't, my code would need to be adapted. The underlying logic is what I wanted to convey. Thanks for enhancing and correcting it!